# Choose sidebars column in widgets.php page

Tags: customization, widgets, sidebar

I know that sidebars appear on `widgets.php` page in order that you register the sidebars. So

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('First', 'mytheme'),
    ....
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => __('Second', 'mytheme'),
    ....
));

.
.
.
```

This will be ordered like

First

Second

Third

But, say I have five registered sidebars. Then in first `sidebars-column-1` I'll have three, and in `sidebars-column-2` I'll have two sidebars.

Is there a way to choose what sidebar will go in which column? Since I have five sidebars: `Primary`, `Search Result`, `First Footer Widget`, `Second Footer Widget`, `Third Footer Widget`

I'd like to have all footer ones on right side, and my `Primary` and `Search` one in the left column.

Can this be done?